# How can I modify style of Vue stacked b-table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I used stacked b-table in bootstrap-vue.

```
   <b-modal :id="infoModal.id" :title="infoModal.title" hide-footer @hide="resetInfoModal;">
        <pre>
            <b-table stacked sticky-header head-variant="light" :items="infoModal.content" :fields="reviewFields"></b-table>
        </pre>
        <template>
            <div class="overflow-auto">
                <b-pagination-nav :link-gen="linkGen" :number-of-pages="10" use-router></b-pagination-nav>
            </div>
        </template>
    </b-modal>
```

this is result:

[image]

[image]

First, I want to move the marked baseline to the left.

Second, content in the table exceeds the outline (red line) of the table. I want the content to be scrollable within a fixed column of the table.

How can I get these effects?

Answer (score 0):

You could set style on each columns

```
reviewFields: [
  { key: 'key0', label: 'label0', class: 'css-class' },
  { key: 'key1', label: 'label1', class: 'css-class' },
  { key: 'key2', label: 'label2', class: 'css-class' },
  { key: 'key3', label: 'label3', class: 'css-class' },
  { key: 'key4', label: 'label4', class: 'css-class' },
]
```